# which one of the following statements is false for these vector fields?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields, scalar-fields

If f is a scalar field and **F** is a vector field, Which one of the following statements is false?

1. $$\nabla^2(fg) = f\nabla^2g + g\nabla^2f + 2\nabla f \cdot \nabla g$$ for any twice differentiable scalar fields f and g
2. There is a vector field $\mathbf{F}$ such that $\nabla \times \mathbf{F} = (x,y,z)$
3. Any vector field of the form $\mathbf{F}(x,y,z)= (f(y,z), g(x,z), h(x,y))$ is solenoidal
4. Any vector field of the form $\mathbf{F}(x,y,z)= (f(x), g(x), h(x))$ is irrotational

Comment: Thanks for editing it properly

Answer (score 0):

1 is true by just applying the product rules for divergence and gradient:
$$\nabla^2(fg)=\nabla\cdot(\nabla(fg))$$
$$=\nabla\cdot[f\nabla g+g\nabla f]$$
$$=f\nabla^2g+g\nabla^2f+\nabla f\cdot \nabla g+\nabla g\cdot\nabla f $$
$$=f\nabla^2g+g\nabla^2f+2\nabla f\cdot \nabla g$$

2 is false. This is because we know that:
$$\nabla\cdot(\nabla \times \mathbf{F})=0$$
And:
$$\nabla\cdot\langle x,y,z\rangle=3$$
3 is also true. A function is solenoidal if it has zero divergence:
$$\nabla\cdot\langle f(y,z),g(x,z),h(x,y) \rangle=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(y,z)+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}g(x,z)+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}h(x,y)$$
$$=0$$
Lastly, 4 is true is as well. A vector field is irrotational if it has zero curl:
$$\nabla\times \mathbf{F}=\langle \frac{\partial}{\partial y}h(z)-\frac{\partial}{\partial z}g(y),
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f(x)-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}h(z),
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(y)-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x) \rangle$$
Which is clearly equal to the zero vector, therefore there is no curl.

If you did not make a typo on the last question then this question is also false and we have:
$$\nabla\times\mathbf{F}=\langle \frac{\partial}{\partial y}h(x)-\frac{\partial}{\partial z}g(x),
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f(x)-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}h(x),
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x)-\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f(x) \rangle$$
$$=\langle 0,-h'(x),g'(x) \rangle$$
Which is not zero.

Comment: In question 4, $g$ and $h$ are functions of $x$, not of $y$ and $z$.

Comment: @TonyK Seems I misread the question, will update accordingly. Though I do believe the author of the question may have made  typo as then there are two false statements.

Comment: hi, number four is F(x,y,z) = (f(x),g(y),h(z)) is irrotational. Thats how the question was given to me, so there was no typos on my behalf. I understand the answer now thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @flowergirl there is then a typo in your question. you define $\mathbf{F}=\langle  f(x), g(x), h(x) \rangle$. You should fix this with an edit.

Comment: what I wrote in the comment here is what I wrote when I submitted the question however when the question was reviewed someone changed it which I couldn't undo.